# Array gives correct output for this mergesort function but vector is giving incorrect output. What is going wrong?

Tags: c++, syntax, mergesort

I've been trying to do the count inversions question using mergesort for the past 2-3 days and after much trying, I just picked up the answer from Hackerrank's editorial, now their code is using an `Array`, and if I use a `Vector` instead of an `Array`, the answer is `Actual answer + 1` (or different to say the least haven't tried it on many cases). I was wondering what might be the reason for it.

I also have another question on explanation of this code, in particular the variable declarations and their use in the mergei function. I understand the rest of the code conceptually, but because of this part, I have some confusion.

```
    int ni = ((i+j)/2) + 1, nj = j + 1;
    int s = i;
    int* arr = new int [j - i + 1];
    j = ni; int k = 0;
```

Code:

```
void mergei(int a[], int i, int j) {
    int ni = ((i+j)/2) + 1, nj = j + 1;
    int s = i;
    int* arr = new int [j - i + 1];
    j = ni; int k = 0;

    while(i < ni && j < nj) {
        if(a[i] <= a[j]) {
            arr[k++] = a[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = a[j++];
            ans += (ni-i);
        }
    }

    for(; i < ni; i++, k++) arr[k] = a[i];
    for(; j < nj; j++, k++) arr[k] = a[j];
    for(k = 0; s < nj; s++, k++) a[s] = arr[k];
    delete [] arr;
}

void m_sort(int a[], int i, int j) {
    if(i < j) {
        m_sort(a, i, (i+j)/2);
        m_sort(a, ((i+j)/2) + 1, j);
        mergei(a, i, j);
    }
}

int main() {
    // vector<int> a = {2, 1, 3, 1, 2};
    int a[] = {2, 1, 3, 1, 2};
    // int n = a.size();
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    m_sort(a, 0, n - 1);
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code statement by statement in a debugger to see when and where something goes wrong or something unexpected happens?

Comment: @G.M. when I use vector, I do a.size() instead!, it still gives wrong answer and I also tried to just put n = 5, still wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't know how to set up debugger in VSCode for c++ yet, I tried, but it opens a debugger for Javascript instead, I will be learning how to use it properly, but for the time being, I don't know how

Comment: There is no difference in output. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/hHZw4p) How do you define `ans`?

Comment: I used [codechef ide](https://www.codechef.com/ide) and it gives 4 for array and 5 for vector, okay turns out I was using ```vector<int> arr``` instead of ```vector<int>& arr``` does that make a difference in this case?
ans is a global variable ```long ans = 0;``` The online compiler you use looks so much better! Can I also debug using that?

Comment: If you just pass in `vector<int> a`, then you are passing in a copy of the vector. Using `&` passes by reference. Since using copies wouldn't sort the original, your comparisons and where `ans` gets incremented would be different.

Comment: Yes I knew that, turns out my confusion about arrays and them being passed as value pointer (changes made will persist, even though not passed by reference), led me to this confusion, finally understood it, in case of vector, only the copy is changed with no effect to the original vector, thanks mate! I must've been confusing these two things and why I thought the vector ```[]``` is different

Answer (score 0):

I was not passing the Vector by reference, something I didn't have to worry about in case of array.